# Adding constraints in grammar for Grammatical Evolution

Tags: formal-grammars, genetic-algorithms, tree-grammars

I'm trying to use Grammatical Evolution for creating trading strategies. Each sentence in the grammar when evaluated gives a weight matrix of size n x p . (n is the length of backtesting period and p is the total number of stocks in portfolio)

BNF form of Grammar

```
<expr>  ::= (<foptr>(<expr>,<expr>,<day>))| 
        (<fopbi>(<expr>,<day>))| 
        (<fopun>(<expr>))| 
        (<expr><matbi><expr>)  |
        <var>
<foptr> ::= corr | covariance
<fopbi> ::= mean |    
            sma|
            ema
<fopun> ::= rank| -1* | 1/ 
<matbi> ::= + | - | * | /
<var> ::= Open|High|Low|Close|Volume
<day> ::=  5 | 10 | 15 | 20
```

The problem is some expressions in this grammar do not make sense. For example, we cannot have a strategy like $Volume/Volume$ or $Low-Low$, etc. And some of the strategies do not have any physical significance, for example, the strategy $Volume+Close$ is not valid as the units of volume and close are different. Any suggestions/references on how to add these constraints to the grammar or circumventing this issue in genetic algorithms will be helpful.

Comment: Have you listed all of the constraints you want to add?  It looks like you've only listed some examples of constraints.  That's not a substitute for a general specification of the constraints you want to add -- i.e., what is the general rule you want to enforce.  We can't guess what that general rule is.

Comment: I think I understand the general question and your example of an "unphysical" (mixing dimensions) expression, but I don't understand your examples of expressions that "do not make sense". Wouldn't $Low - Low$ just give a 0 matrix? What's wrong with 0?

Comment: @D.W. I'm sorry I don't have a general rule for constraints as of now. I was just wondering if at all I know some invalid rules, how do I eliminate them from the grammar.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg The problem is if we are allowing a null matrix, then we are also allowing 1/null matrix as a valid expression, which doesn't make sense. Also, it will unnecessarily increase the length of the expression. For example, Close-Low+Low.

Comment: The dimensions problem is relatively easy to deal with in a number of ways (see D.W.'s answer for one), but disallowing anything that could result in a null matrix is much harder. You are essentially asking to disallow any expression, however complicated, that could result in a zero value. What if a day opens and closes at the same value, so $Open - Close = 0$? Is that a disallowed expression too?

Comment: @AaronRotenberg In the example you specified, that happens only for a few days and that too for a set of stocks. We will still have non zero values in that row, which makes sense financially. If the whole portfolio has Open = Close for all days of the backtest, then the expression is meaningless.

Comment: Re: unnecessarily increasing the length of the expression, you can deal with this by adding a regularization term penalizing long expressions. This can be justified from Occam's razor, since shorter models are simpler hypotheses. But that doesn't _disallow_ unnecessarily long terms, just make them less likely to be selected.

Comment: The way to enforce a constraint will depend on what constraint you want to enforce, so if you don't know what ones you want to enforce, we can't tell you how to modify the grammar to enforce them.

Comment: A few constraints which I can think of: 1. (<expr><matbi><expr>) cannot have the same expression on both sides of the operator. The same thing applies to (<foptr>(<expr>,<expr>,<day>)) 2. Constraint on the number of operators in an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce that units match by duplicating nonterminals, one per unit.  For instance, instead of `var`, you can have `varA` and `varB` (if A and B are the two types of units); instead of `expr`, you can have `exprA` and `exprB`; with rules like `<varA> ::= Close`, `<varB> ::= Volume`, `<exprA> ::= ...|<exprA><matbi><exprA>|...|varA`, `<exprB> ::= ...|<exprB><matbi><exprB>|...|varB`, and so on.

There's no good way to modify the grammar to ensure that it cannot generate any expression that would evaluate to 0.  That is best handled by other methods, not by changing the grammar.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg, oops, yes.  Thanks!  Fixed!